# Multiple elements in a 0-d Numpy array

Tags: matlab, numpy, scipy

I'm reading a `*.mat` file (not sure of Matlab version that was used) with `scipy.io.loadmat` in Python 2.6, and I'm not able to work with the arrays read due to the array dimensioning.  It seems that however I attempt to access the elements, I end up with a 0-d array that still has multiple elements.  I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773030/why-are-0d-arrays-in-numpy-not-considered-scalar) and [this](http://projects.scipy.org/numpy/wiki/ZeroRankArray), but am still stuck as to how to work with the elements.

Let's say I read an array,

```
data = scipy.io.loadmat(filename,squeeze_me=False)
....
b = data[0][0]['somevar']
```

after this, I have

```
b=  [[ array([[ 1.0884988 ,  1.08116209,  1.07364911,  1.06662874,  1.06008637,
                1.0530468 ,  1.04619028,  1.03984295,  1.03342865,  1.02715746,
                1.02114066,  1.01496634,  1.00904967,  1.00316573,  0.99803184,
                0.99262961 ]])]]
```

Now, if I attempt `b.squeeze()` or `b = b[0][0]`, I have

```
b=  [[ 1.0884988   1.08116209  1.07364911  1.06662874  1.06008637  
       1.0530468   1.04619028  1.03984295  1.03342865  1.02715746  
       1.02114066  1.01496634  1.00904967  1.00316573  0.99803184  
       0.99262961]]
```

which is a 0-d array, and naturally end up with the error

```
IndexError: 0-d arrays can't be indexed
```

or the like, and cannot access the elements of `b`.

How can I access the elements of the array initially read from `loadmat` without producing a 0-d array, and preferably with more elegance than using multiple `[0]` indices?  Thanks for any help or suggestions.

Comment: Could you post a link to your data? I use `loadmat` all the time and have found squeezing to be the solution in one way or another.

Comment: Well, 0-d arrays can be indexed anyway. Use array.item() or array[()].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I type b at the Python prompt like you show, I get a structure where I can access the "real" array via `b[0][0].squeeze()` - regardless of whether the inner array is an `array` from the Python library or a `numpy.array`. In other words, works for me.

Comment: Thanks - I'm able to index the elements with this.  Is there any more elegant/Python-ish way to extract these elements, besides using `b[0][0].squeeze`?

Comment: That's just what you get for using loadmat - it reads a file that's adapted to Matlab's idiosyncratic data structures, and those don't necessarily map naturally to Python/Numpy's data structures.