# Unable to load non-arrays from an npz file

Tags: python, numpy, io

I need to save several numpy arrays and Python objects to disk.I  want to completely minimize the I/O. I don't mind if the loader or saver has to do any lifting in memory, but the **I/O footprint** (actual access) should be the lowest, since we have problems in our cluster when many jobs access the filesystem at the same time.

I tried with:

```
import numpy as np

my_data = dict()

my_data['r1'] = np.random.randint(3, size=(100,200))
my_data['rs'] = np.random.randint(3, size=(50,400))

my_data['annotation_info'] = 'Two random arrays'
my_data['current_date']    = 'July 28' 

np.savez('test.npz', my_data = my_data)
```

But when I load this, I get:

```
temp = np.load('test.npz')
my_data = temp['my_data']
my_data['r1']

ValueError: field named features not found
```

Also, `my_data` seems to now be an array, with `my_data.shape` returning `()`. Oddly enough, if I do:

```
print(my_data)
```

I get:

```
{'current_date': 'July 28', 'rs': array([[0, 1, 0, ..., 0, 2, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 0],
       [2, 1, 1, ..., 1, 1, 0],
       ..., 
       [1, 0, 2, ..., 2, 0, 1],
       [0, 2, 0, ..., 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, ..., 1, 1, 1]]), 'annotation_info': 'Two random arrays', '
r1': array([[2, 0, 1, ..., 0, 2, 2],                                      
       [0, 0, 2, ..., 0, 2, 1],
       [2, 2, 2, ..., 1, 0, 0],
       ..., 
       [0, 2, 1, ..., 2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, ..., 2, 1, 0],
       [2, 1, 2, ..., 0, 2, 2]])}
```

## Update

If I do what unutbu recommends:

```
np.savez('test.npz', **my_data)
my_data = np.load('test.npz')
my_variable = my_data['annotation_info']
```

`my_variable` is not a string, e.g. `my_variable.upper()` returns:

```
numpy.ndarray object has no attribute 'upper'
```

In fact `type(my_variable)` returns:

```
numpy.ndarray
```

But again, `my_variable[0]` throws an error, and `my_variable.shape` returns `()` (which seems to be a [`0-Rank array`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773030/why-are-0d-arrays-in-numpy-not-considered-scalar))

How can I access the actual object stored in the array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
np.savez('test.npz', **my_data)
my_data = np.load('test.npz')
print(my_data['r1'])
```

NumPy saves the strings as NumPy arrays. To access the strings as Python objects, you could use the `item` method:

```
my_data = np.load('test.npz')
my_variable = my_data['annotation_info'].item()
```