# Conditional coloring in Matplotlib using Numpy's where

Tags: python, matplotlib

What I want to achieve is to conditionally color my scatter plot. I followed this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40803570/python-matplotlib-scatter-plot-specify-color-points-depending-on-conditions/40804861#), but I get `TypeError: len() of unsized object`. I'm doing the following

```
for i in range(n_cells):
   col = np.where(cell_list[i].m_n == 1, 'g', 'k')
   plt.scatter(cell_list[i].x, cell_list[i].y, c = col, alpha = 0.5, s = 2)
```

`cell_list` is an array of `cell`s, which is a user-defined object. I have checked and ensured that `col` is an array of `g` and `k` of the correct size. Moreover, if you change `c = col` to `c = 'b'` for example, the plot works correctly. I'm relatively new to Python, so I cannot find what the issue is.

Comment: For more specific help, please post a [reprex].

Comment: It is hard for us to test the code, but I believe np.where always returns a numpy object. Have you tried `c = str(col)` ? This seems to work on my end.

Comment: The code you posted could raise that TypeError if `cell_list[i].x` is a [NumPy scalar](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21968643/190597) (such as `np.array(1)`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since np.where always returns a numpy object, using str(col) works for the following script.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

col = np.where(0 == 1, 'g', 'k')
plt.scatter([0, 1], [0, 1], c = str(col), alpha = 0.5, s = 2)

plt.show()
```