# is there a pythonic way to change scalar and 0d-array to 1d array?

Tags: python, numpy

For example, I want to change 'a' to 0 if 'a' is less than 5

```
def foo(a):
    return 0 if a < 5 else a
```

to make it work for numpy array, I it change to:

```
def foo2(a):
    a[a < 5] = 0
    return a
```

The problem is that I want the function work for both scalar and arrays.

The isscalar() function can test if 'a' is a scalar, but it returns false for 0d-arrays, like array(12).

Is there a pythonic way to change scalar and 0d-array to 1d array and remain other ndarray unchanged?

Comment: Scalars can't be indexed, you'll need to handle the scalar case separately, possibly by converting it to a 0d-array first then back.

Comment: You can use `a.ndim == 0` to recognize 0d-array. Take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773030/why-are-0d-arrays-in-numpy-not-considered-scalar

Comment: 0d-array cannot be indexed either, so I want to change them to 1d-arrays, but I just cannot find a good way to do this.

Comment: The error message is misleading; 0-dimensional arrays can be indexed. `zero_d_array[()]` or `zero_d_array[...]` both work. There does seem to be a weird edge case with boolean advanced indexing, though.

Comment: Are you sure you want your function to modify `a` in place? That'll produce strange inconsistencies between the scalar and array cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `np.atleast_1d`

This will work for any input (scalar or array):

```
def foo(a):
    a = np.atleast_1d(a)
    a[a < 5] = 0
    return a
```

Note though, that this will return a 1d array for a scalar input.

Comment: This needs to be slightly modified to return scalars. The best example I found so far is https://stackoverflow.com/a/29319864/7919597. You need use `np.array` or `np.asarray` to convert the input. Then check if the number of dimensions is 0. If a dimension is added using `np.newaxis`, `None` or `np.atleast1d`, you need to use remove it later, e.g. using np.squeeze or just a[0].

Answer (score 4):

well, I come with a solution that seems to work

```
def foo3(a):
    return a * (a >= 5)

foo3(4)
=> 0

foo3(6)
=> 6

foo3(np.array(3))
=> 0

foo3(np.array(6))
=> 6

foo3(np.array([1, 5]))
=> array([0, 5])
```

It works fine, but I don't know whether it is safe to do so.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`numpy.vectorize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html), with the original scalar implemenation.

```
@np.vectorize
def foo(a):
   return 0 if a < 5 else a

foo(3)
=> array(0)
foo(7)
=> array(7)
foo([[3,7], [8,-1]])
=> array([[0, 7],
          [8, 0]])
```

Note that when using `vectorize`, you give up speed (your calculation is no longer vectorized in the numpy/C level) for simplicity (you write your function in its simple form, for scalars).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind the function returning an array even if it is supplied with a scalar, I'd be inclined to do it this way:

```
import numpy as np

def foo(a,k=5):
    b = np.array(a)
    if not b.ndim:
        b = np.array([a])
    b[b < k] = 0
    return b

print(foo(3))
print(foo(6))
print(foo([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]))
print(foo(np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])))
```

... which produces the results:

```
[0]
[6]
[0 0 0 0 5 6 7 8 9]
[0 0 0 0 5 6 7 8 9]
```

As you can see from the test examples, this function works as intended if it is supplied with a regular Python list instead of a `numpy` array or a scalar.

Creating two arrays in the process may seem wasteful but, first, creating `b` prevents the function from having unwanted side-effects. Consider that:

```
def foobad(a,k=5):
    a[a < k] = 0
    return a

x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])
foobad(x)
print (x)
```

... prints:

```
[0 0 0 0 5 6 7 8 9]
```

... which is probably not what was desired by the user of the function. Second, if the second array creation occurs because the function was supplied with a scalar, it will only be creating an array from a 1-element list, which should be very quick.

Answer (score 0):

This is an answer to the last part of your question. A quick way to change a scalar or a 0d array to a 1d array using `np.reshape` after checking the dimension with `np.ndim`.

```
import numpy as np

a = 1
if np.ndim(a) == 0:
    np.reshape(a, (-1))
=> array([1])
```

Then,

```
b = np.array(1)
=> array(1) # 0d array
if np.ndim(b) == 0:
    np.reshape(b, (-1))
=> array([1]) # 1d array. you can iterate over this.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
def foo(a, b=5):
    ix = a < b
    if not np.isscalar(ix):
        a[ix] = 0
    elif ix:
        a = 0
    return a

print([foo(1), foo(10), foo(np.array(1)), foo(np.array(10)), foo(np.arange(10))])
```

Outputs

```
[0, 10, 0, array(10), array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])]
```

Note that `array(1) > 0` gives `bool` instead of `np.bool_`, so safe to use `np.isscalar` for `ix`.

Answer (score 0):

Reapeating my [answer elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63582814/7625874),

The `numpy` functions naturally handle scalar or nd array inputs and preserve the shape in the output. So, it's always best to find the `numpy` functions doing the job. In this case, `np.where` is your friend.

```py
def foo(a):
    return np.where(a<5, a, 0)

foo(6)
> array(0)
foo(np.array([3,4,5,6]))
> array([3, 4, 0, 0])
```