# TypeError / Array indexing; 'int' object does not support item assignment

Tags: python, numpy

I have a function which works on arrays with more than one item, but fails if the array contains only one item. Let's consider this example

```
import numpy as np

def checker(a):
   a[a>5] = np.nan

a = np.arange(10)
a = checker(a)
```

Works, but

```
a = 1
a = checker(a)   # fails
```

and gives

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   a[a>5] = np.nan
   TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment
```

I'd like to handle it like MATLAB, and NOT like this version of checker(), which has 4x more lines than the version above.

```
def checker(a):
   try:
      a[a>5] = np.nan
   except TypeError:
      if a>5: a = np.nan
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Comment: I'm trying to calculate something, provided some conditions are met

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MATLAB everything has atleast 2 dimensons; in `numpy` indexing can reduce the number of dimensions

```
np.shape(1)
```

is `()`?  This is the same as `np.array(1).shape`, i.e. the shape (size in MATLAB terms) of a single element array.  It is 0d, as opposed to 2d in MATLAB.

```
a = np.empty(np.shape(1))*np.nan
# a = np.array(np.nan) does the same thing
```

is `nan`, a single element array with value `nan`.

```
a[False]
```

displays as `array([], dtype=float)`, with shape `(0,)`; it's now 1d, but without any elements.

With a 0d array, the only meaningful indexing is `a[()]` which returns the element, `nan`, a `np.float64`.  `a.item()` does the same.

And for assignment purposes I can't find a way to change the value of that item

```
a[???] = 0
```

correction, ellipsis can be used, since it stands in for any number of `:` including none.

```
a[...] = 0
# array(0,0)
```

(you don't wand `a=0` since that just reassigns the variable).

In general 0d arrays like this are possible, but they are rarely useful.

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to do (I don't have a working Octave session at the moment).  But this difference in how dimensions change with indexing is the key to your problems.

```
a = np.array([np.nan])
a[np.array([False])] = 0   # no change
a[np.array([True])] = 0    # change
```

Note that I made the boolean index an array, but just a scalar or list.  This is closer to your MATLAB boolean index.

Comment: It ultimately yields to following questions: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25458553/is-there-a-pythonic-way-to-change-scalar-and-0d-array-to-1d-array

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773030/why-are-0d-arrays-in-numpy-not-considered-scalar?lq=1

Comment: That link reminded me that `a[...]=0` can be used to change values of any dimensional object.  But I don't see how that would help with the change/don't change issue.

Answer (score 0):

To create an empty array filled with `nan`s, you can use `np.fill`:

```
a=np.empty(np.shape(1))
a.fill(np.nan)
b=False

a[b]=10
```

You were getting an error because `a` wasn't an array, it was a float.

Answer (score 0):

When you multiply a scalar array by a scalar, numpy coerces the result into a scalar:

```
>>> a = np.empty(())
>>> a
array(10.0)
>>> a * 2
20.0
```

If you need to keep the scalar as an array, you can use `np.asarray(a * 2)`