# Numpy append to an empty array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

1st case :

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x=np.array(0)
>>> x=np.append(x,1)
>>> x
array([0, 1])
```

`x` contains 2 elements. Why is that ?!

2nd case :

```
>>> x=np.array([])
>>> x=np.append(x,1)
>>> x
array([ 1.])
```

`x` contains 1 element, as expected.

What's the difference between `np.array(0)` and `np.array([])` ?

Comment: `np.array(0)` is an array containing 0. whereas `np.array([])` is an empty array containing nothing.

Comment: The real lesson to learn here is to check your results in between evaluations, it would have became obvious.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your first case, you are creating an array called `x` that will containing one value, which is `0`.

In your second case you are creating an empty array called `x` that will contain no values, but is still an array.

**FIRST CASE**

So when you append `x = np.append(x,1)`, the value `1` get's appended to your array (which already contains 0) **i.e. it now contains 0 and 1**

**SECOND CASE**

Since you have no values in the empty array, when you append `x=np.append(x,1)` the value `1` get's appended and the length of `x` becomes 1 (**i.e. it now contains only 1**)

P.S. I believe you might have thought that calling `x = np.array(0)` with the `0` would make it an empty array, it doesn't!! In Python, 0 is still taken to be a number and is appended to the array.

Comment: Are you sure the 1st case create a 1-item array ? x.shape is ().

Comment: @dplamp yes, you are true.. But as mentioned in my answer, when you create `x = np.array(0)` you are creating `x` with the value `0`. So whatever you are going to append further to `x` will contain `0` along with the appended value

Comment: That is not quite true, I think. My mistake is that array() takes an array-like object as its 1st argument, which is not the case in my '1st case'. Yet, it silently accepts it, which leads to a strange behaviour down the line. Hard to admit for a C++ guy...

Comment: @dplamp This is expected behavior. `array(0)` a 'zero-dimensional' array, while `array([0])` is a one-dimensional array.

Comment: @dplamp `x = np.array(0)` creates a _scalar_, which is still an `array` (hence, `type(x)` would return `numpy.ndarray`), but is of empty shape. The whole handling of scalars vs. one-dimensional arrays seems a bit messy in numpy in general. Have a look at the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.scalars.html) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773030/why-are-0d-arrays-in-numpy-not-considered-scalar) answer to get a bit more insight.