# Copied dictionary via numpy.copy. Now is ndarray; how to recover the original dictionary?

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary

This is surely a silly mistake, as I was not aware of the dict.copy functionality. The problem is that I had a dictionary full of data, say `x`, that I copied to another variable, say `y`, by doing `y=numpy.copy(x)`. The thing is that later I saved the variable `y` and wrote it to a pickle (and I repeated this several times, writing several files; its part of a very long simulation!). Now when I open the pickle, I get an `ndarray` object which contains my dictionary but inside a `ndarray` object, and I have no idea on how to retrieve the original dictionary with the original data. A working example:

```
import numpy
x = {'a':[1,2,3], 'b':['foo','bar']}
y = numpy.copy(x)
```

I have tried lots of things with no success; is there actually a way to retrieve the original dictionary, `x`, from the new variable `y`?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my testing somehow `y.tolist()` gives the original dict back. Maybe try that `:)`

Some more sensible methods perhaps I got from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/773030/2379410):

```
y[()]
```

And:

```
y.item()
```

Comment: I can't believe this didn't occured to me, thank you so much!

Comment: @Néstor, Well a method with a name `tolist` that returns a dict strikes me as somewhat odd

Comment: But is somewhat intuitive, as working with lists is always by far less complicated than with numpy arrays.

Answer (score 1):

One way:

```
d = y.ravel()[0]
d.keys()
```

gives

```
['a', 'b']
```