# how to create ndarray with ndim==0 and size==0?

Tags: python, numpy

I am testing some edge cases of my program and observed a strange fact. When I create a scalar numpy array, it has `size==1` and `ndim==0`.

```
>>> A=np.array(1.0)
>>> A.ndim  # returns 0
>>> A.size  # returns 1
```

But when I create empty array with no element, then it has `size==0` but `ndim==1`.

```
>>> A=np.array([])
>>> A.ndim  # returns 1
>>> A.size  # returns 0
```

Why is that? I would expect the `ndim` to be also `0`. Or is there another way of creation of 'really' empty array with `size` and `ndim` equal to `0`?

UPDATE: even `A=np.empty(shape=None)` does not create dimensionless array of size 0...

Comment: Because it's a **1**-D array.

Comment: OK, I agree... if I used `A=np.array([[]])` I would get `ndim==2`... This seems logical. But is there a way to create a dimensionless array with size 0?

Comment: I rewrote the title of my question a bit.

Comment: What use do you have for such a contraption?

Comment: I am asking for two reasons: 1) curiosity, which is a thing that will help you understand and learn 2) my function/class/whatever takes a numpy ndarray and does some pretty complicated operations on it. I found it fails when I put scalar in it so I rewrote it to become more robust. Then I found it fails when I put empty multidimensional array in it so I rewrote it again... I finally if it is possible to put a zero dimension array of size zero, I am likely to rewrite it again. But I do not know if such a thing - zero dimensional array with size of zero - even exists...

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer is that "No, you can't create an `ndarray` with both `ndim` and `size` of zero". As you've already found out yourself, the `(ndim,size)` pairs of `(1,0)` and `(0,1)` are as low as you can go.

[This very nice answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/794812/5067311) explains a lot about numpy scalar types, and why they're a bit odd to have around. This explanation makes it clear that scalar numpy arrays like `array(1)` are a very special kind of beast. They only have a single value (causing `size==1`), but by definition they don't have a sense of dimensionality, hence `ndim==0`. Non-scalar numpy arrays, on the other hand, can be empty, but they contain at least a pair of square brackets, leading to a minimal `ndim` of 1, even if their `size` can be 0 if they are made up of empty lists. (This is how I think about the situation: `ndarray`s are in a way lists of lists of lists of ..., on as many levels as there are dimensions. 1d arrays are compatible with lists, so an *empty* list, being still a list, also has a defining dimension.)

The only way to come up with an empty scalar would be to call `np.array()` like this, but arrays can only be initialized by some actual object. So I believe your program is safe from this edge case.