# Why a single Numpy array element is not a Python scalar?

Tags: python, numpy

Can someone explain the Numpy design decision to keep single elements of arrays as distinct from Python scalars?

The following code works without errors

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1, 2, 3])
b = a[0]
print(b.size)
```

This illustrates that `b` is not a simple Python scalar, and in fact `type(b)` gives `numpy.int32` instead of `int`.

Of course, if one defines `b = 1`, the command `b.size` throws an error because

> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'size'

I find this difference of behaviour confusing and I am wondering what is its motivation.

Comment: This question is relevant, possibly a duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773030/why-are-0d-arrays-in-numpy-not-considered-scalar

Comment: This page of documentation seems to claim that default python functionality would cause incorrect behavior if used in many scientific computing settings: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.scalars.html

Comment: @ajcr The same answer likely applies to this question, but the question itself does not strike me as a duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a difference between elements of an array and the object you get when indexing one.

The array has a data buffer.  It is a block of bytes the numpy manages with its own compiled code.  Individual elements may be represented by 1 byte, 4, 8, 16, etc.

```
In [478]: A=np.array([1,2,3])

In [479]: A.__array_interface__
Out[479]: 
{'data': (167487856, False),
 'descr': [('', '<i4')],
 'shape': (3,),
 'strides': None,
 'typestr': '<i4',
 'version': 3}
```

view the data as a list of bytes (displayed as characters):

```
In [480]: A.view('S1')
Out[480]: 
array(['\x01', '', '', '', '\x02', '', '', '', '\x03', '', '', ''], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

When you select an element of `A` you get back a one element array (or something like it):

```
In [491]: b=A[0]

In [492]: b.shape
Out[492]: ()

In [493]: b.__array_interface__
Out[493]: 
{'__ref': array(1),
 'data': (167480104, False),
 'descr': [('', '<i4')],
 'shape': (),
 'strides': None,
 'typestr': '<i4',
 'version': 3}
```

The `type` is different, but `b` has most of the same attributes as `A`, `shape`, `strides`, `mean`, etc.

You have to use `.item` to access the underlying 'scalar':

```
In [496]: b.item()
Out[496]: 1

In [497]: type(b.item())
Out[497]: int
```

So you can think of `b` as a scalar with a `numpy` wrapper.  The `__array_interface__` for `b` looks very much like that of `np.array(1)`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clear answer. Of course this explains what the difference really is, but not why this design choice was made. Is the distinction merely due to a technical limitation, because Numpy is just a package of Python (unlike e.g. MATLAB, or Mathematica, or IDL)? Or was the Numpy choice better than the MATLAB one, where the distinction does not exist?

Comment: `size(x(1))` returns `1,1` in Octave/MATLAB.  In the original MATLAB everything was a 2d matrix; there were no scalars.  That's weakened a bit in new versions.

Comment: The key difference is that in MATLAB `size(1)` is identical to `size(x(1))`: they both return `1,1`. A single array element is indistinguishable from a scalar. This is not the case in Numpy.