# Why is a `for` over a Python list faster than over a Numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

So without telling a really long story I was working on some code where I was reading in some data from a binary file and then looping over every single point using a for loop. So I completed the code and it was running ridiculously slow. I was looping over around 60,000 points from around 128 data channels and this was taking a minute or more to process. This was way slower than I ever expected Python to run. So I made the whole thing more efficient by using Numpy but in trying to figure out why the original process ran so slow we were doing some type checking and found that I was looping over Numpy arrays instead of Python lists. OK no major deal to make the inputs to our test setup the same I converted the Numpy arrays to lists before looping. Bang the same slow code that took a minute to run now took 10 seconds. I was floored. The only think I did was change a Numpy array to a Python list I changed it back and it was slow as mud again. I couldn't believe it so I went to get more definitive proof

```
$ python -m timeit -s "import numpy" "for k in numpy.arange(5000): k+1"
100 loops, best of 3: 5.46 msec per loop

$ python -m timeit "for k in range(5000): k+1"
1000 loops, best of 3: 256 usec per loop
```

What is going on? I know that Numpy arrays and and Python list are different but why is it so much slower to iterate over every point in an array?

I observed this behavior in both Python 2.6 and 2.7 running Numpy 10.1 I believe.

Comment: What Python version are you using?

Comment: Not a numpy expert, but I think the point is that you usually don't want to iterate over numpy arrays with python loops, because then you lose the speed increase (and actually more, because of the overhead).

Comment: To hazard a guess - numpy has to go from the C up to Python to yield up its value, where Python `for` loops are pretty optimal. You might consider looking at `dis.dis(some_func)` to see if there's anything there.

Comment: `numpy.arange` is creating a numpy array and all the overhead that comes with it ... (after the fact it typically is faster to manipulate...)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

We can do a little sleuthing to figure this out:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.arange(32)
>>> a
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16,
       17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31])
>>> a.data
<read-write buffer for 0x107d01e40, size 256, offset 0 at 0x107d199b0>
>>> id(a.data)
4433424176
>>> id(a[0])
4424950096
>>> id(a[1])
4424950096
>>> for item in a:
...   print id(item)
... 
4424950096
4424950120
4424950096
4424950120
4424950096
4424950120
4424950096
4424950120
4424950096
4424950120
4424950096
4424950120
4424950096
4424950120
4424950096
4424950120
4424950096
4424950120
4424950096
4424950120
4424950096
4424950120
4424950096
4424950120
4424950096
4424950120
4424950096
4424950120
4424950096
4424950120
4424950096
4424950120
```

So what is going on here?  First, I took a look at the memory location of the array's memory buffer.  It's at `4433424176`.  That in itself isn't *too* illuminating.  However, numpy stores it's data as a contiguous C array, so the first element in the numpy array *should* correspond to the memory address of the array itself, but it doesn't:

```
>>> id(a[0])
4424950096
```

and it's a good thing it doesn't because that would break the invariant in python that 2 objects never have the same `id` during their lifetimes.

So, how does numpy accomplish this?  Well, the answer is that numpy has to wrap the returned object with a python type (e.g. `numpy.float64` or `numpy.int64` in this case) which takes time if you're iterating item-by-item<sup>1</sup>.  Further proof of this is demonstrated when iterating -- We see that we're alternating between 2 separate IDs while iterating over the array.  This means that python's memory allocator and garbage collector are working overtime to create new objects and then free them.

A *list* doesn't have this memory allocator/garbage collector overhead.  The objects in the list already exist as python objects (and they'll still exist after iteration), so neither plays any role in the iteration over a list.

### Timing methodology:

Also note, your timings are thrown off a little bit by your assumptions.  You were assuming that `k + 1` should take about the same amount of time in both cases, but it doesn't.  Notice if I repeat your timings *without* doing any addition:

```
mgilson$ python -m timeit -s "import numpy" "for k in numpy.arange(5000): k"
1000 loops, best of 3: 233 usec per loop
mgilson$ python -m timeit "for k in range(5000): k"
10000 loops, best of 3: 114 usec per loop
```

there's only about a factor of 2 difference.  Doing the addition however leads to a factor of 5 difference or so:

```
mgilson$ python -m timeit "for k in range(5000): k+1"
10000 loops, best of 3: 179 usec per loop
mgilson$ python -m timeit -s "import numpy" "for k in numpy.arange(5000): k+1"
1000 loops, best of 3: 786 usec per loop
```

For fun, lets just do the addition:

```
$ python -m timeit -s "v = 1" "v + 1"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.0261 usec per loop
mgilson$ python -m timeit -s "import numpy; v = numpy.int64(1)" "v + 1"
10000000 loops, best of 3: 0.121 usec per loop
```

And finally, your timeit also includes list/array construction time which isn't ideal:

```
mgilson$ python -m timeit -s "v = range(5000)" "for k in v: k"
10000 loops, best of 3: 80.2 usec per loop
mgilson$ python -m timeit -s "import numpy; v = numpy.arange(5000)" "for k in v: k"
1000 loops, best of 3: 237 usec per loop
```

Notice that numpy actually got further away from the list solution in this case.  This shows that *iteration* really *is* slower and you might get some speedups if you convert the numpy types to standard python types.

<sup><sup>1</sup>Note, this doesn't take a lot of time when slicing because that only has to allocate O(1) new objects since numpy returns a *view* into the original array.</sup>

Comment: Yeah OK I buy that it seems to mostly be wrapped up in data conversions. I normally do +1 when testing like this because I am unsure if the k will be optimized away. Marked answered

Comment: I demonstrate in http://stackoverflow.com/a/34273109/901925 that `a[0]` has all the properties of an `array`.  There have been other SO questions that ask which is faster, a list or an array.

Comment: @mechsin -- `k` won't be optimized away -- But even if it was, that wouldn't be a huge problem so long as the iteration wasn't.  And the iteration _can't_ be optimized away because there is no way for python to know a-priori if iterating over the item has side-effects (e.g. consuming a generator vs. a non-consumable iterable like a list).

Answer (score 3):

Using python 2.7

Here are my speeds along with xrange:

```
python -m timeit -s "import numpy" "for k in numpy.arange(5000): k+1"
```

**1000 loops, best of 3: 1.22 msec per loop**

```
python -m timeit "for k in range(5000): k+1"
```

**10000 loops, best of 3: 186 usec per loop**

```
python -m timeit "for k in xrange(5000): k+1"
```

**10000 loops, best of 3: 161 usec per loop**

Numpy is noticeibly slower because it's iterating over a numpy-specific array. This is not its primarily intended function. In many cases, they should be treated more like a monolithic collection of numbers as opposed to simple lists/iterables. For example, if we have a rather large-ish python list of numbers that we want to raise to the third power, we might do something like this:

```
python -m timeit "lst1 = [x for x in range(100000)];" "lst2 = map(lambda x: x**3, lst1)"
```

**10 loops, best of 3: 125 msec per loop**

Note: the lst1 represents an arbitrary list. I'm aware you can speed this up within the original lambda by doing x**3 for x in range, but this is dealign with a list that should already exist and may very well not be sequential.

Anyway, numpy is meant to be treated as an array would be:

```
python -m timeit -s "import numpy" "lst1 = numpy.arange(100000)" "lst2 = lst1**2"
```

**10000 loops, best of 3: 120 usec per loop**

Say you had two lists of arbitrary values, each of which you want to multiply together. In vanilla python, you might do:

```
python -m timeit -s "lst1 = [x for x in xrange(0, 10000, 2)]" "lst2 = [x for x in xrange(2, 10002, 2)]" "lst3 = [x*y for x,y in zip(lst1, lst2)]"
```

**1000 loops, best of 3: 736 usec per loop**

And in Numpy:

```
python -m timeit -s "import numpy" "lst1 = numpy.arange(0, 10000, 2)" "lst2 = numpy.arange(2, 10002, 2)" "lst3 = lst1*lst2"
```

**100000 loops, best of 3: 10.9 usec per loop**

In these last two examples, NumPy skyrockets ahead as the clear winner. For simple iteration over a list, range or xrange is perfectly sufficient, but your example does not take into account the true purpose of Numpy arrays. It's comparing planes and cars; yeah, planes are generally faster for what they are intended to do, but trying to fly to your local supermarket is not prudent.

Comment: I optimized the slow code by using vectorization and Numpy arrays so I am well aware that is there intend purpose. I really meant to ask the question I asked which is why is looping over two object that are essentially the same so different. I  think mgilson is probably right it has to do with the data conversions.