# ndarry in numpy: expensive in ndarray iteration

Tags: python, performance, numpy

Here is an interesting observation:

```
1 import numpy as np
2 data = np.array([[255,255,255], [0, 0, 255], [255, 0, 0]], np.int8)
3 for i in range(1000000):
4    for row in data:
5        for col in row:
6            flag = col > 0
```

The above code takes **~17 seconds** to finish. If I convert `data` to list by doing

```
data = data.tolist()
```

Then the whole thing only takes **< 1 second** to finish.

<s>Would like to know:
1. What's the reason for the low efficiency in ndarray value comparison?
2. What's a more appropriate way to do the comparison if I don't convert the the ndarray to list? Would it be more efficient than if I covert it into list?</s>

Thanks!

--------------  edited question: -------------

As @hpaulj pointed out, it's the **iteration** not value comparison that's very expensive. But I do need to iterate thru the array. Any better way than converting it to list?

Comment: It's not the value comparison that's expensive, it's the iteration.  You are supposed to apply the comparison to the whole array.

Comment: I found a bug: np.int8 type cannot store 255. It's a signed type which can only store -128~127. So your data is `np.array([[-1,-1,-1], [0, 0, -1], [-1, 0, 0]], np.int8)` eventually.

Comment: @hpaulj Ya. Agreed. Just figured. But I do need to iterate the whole ndarray. Any better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the side bar: [Why is a `for` over a Python list faster than over a Numpy array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35232406/why-is-a-for-over-a-python-list-faster-than-over-a-numpy-array)

The question of how to make iteration over an array faster comes up often - and best answer is "don't", or rather, push the iteration onto compiled `numpy` code.  There's no way to make explicit iteration at the Python level significantly faster.  Some tricks may yield a 2x speedup, but not an order of magnitude.

So in your case, the answer is `it depends on what you are doing at each iteration`.  As `gzc's` answer shows, you can perform the comparison, element by element, with one `numpy` expression.  You don't need to iterate to perform that action.

Answer (score 1):

A more appropriate and effecient way is to use numpy element-wise comparison.

```
for i in range(1000000):
    flag = data > 0
```