# zip rows of pandas DataFrame with list/array of values

Tags: python, pandas

My current code is

```
from numpy import *

def buildRealDataObject(x):
    loc = array(x[0])
    trueClass = x[1]
    evid = ones(len(loc))
    evid[isnan(loc)] = 0
    loc[isnan(loc)] = 0
    return DataObject(location=loc, trueClass=trueClass, evidence=evid)

if trueClasses is None:
    trueClasses = zeros(len(dataset), dtype=int8).tolist()    
realObjects = list(map(lambda x: buildRealDataObject(x), zip(dataset, trueClasses)))
```

and it is working. What I expect is to create for each row of the DataFrame `dataset` each combined with the corresponding entry of `trueClasses` a `realObject`. I am not really sure though why it is working because if run `list(zip(dataset, trueClasses))` I just get something like `[(0, 0.0), (1, 0.0)]`. The two columns of `dataset` are called `0` and `1`. So my first question is: **Why is this working and what is happening here?**

However I think this might still be wrong on some level, because it might only work due to "clever implicit transformation" on side of pandas. Also, for the line `evid[isnan(loc)] = 0` I now got the error

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

**How should I rewrite this code instead?**

Comment: You could looks mystical, e.g. where is `isnan` from, and not very pythonic?. You better try giving some input, and tell people what's your expected output.

Comment: @zyxue: It's from numpy.

Comment: Give minimal executable code so people can copy/paste to see the exception you describe, otherwise people have to guess what dataset is, and what DataObject is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently the zip works on columns instead of rows. Use one of the method from [Pandas convert dataframe to array of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9758450/pandas-convert-dataframe-to-array-of-tuples) to make the zip work on rows instead of columns. For example substitute

```
zip(dataset, trueClasses)
```

with

```
zip(dataset.values, trueClasses)
```

Considiering [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35232645/4533188), if you have already `l = list(data_train.values)` for some reason, then `zip(l, eClass)` is faster than `zip(dataset.values, trueClasses)`. However, if you don't then the transformation takes too much time to make it worth it in my tests.