# Scipy interpolate returns a 'dimensionless' array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I understand that `interp1d` expects an array of values to interpolate, but the behavior when passing it a float is strange enough to ask what is going on and what exactly is being returned

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

x = np.array([1,2,3,4])
y = np.array([5,7,9,15])
f = interp1d(x,y, kind='cubic')
a = f(2.5)

print(repr(a))
print("type is {}".format(type(a)))
print("shape is {}".format(a.shape))
print("ndim is {}".format(a.ndim))
print(a)
```

Output:

```
array(7.749999999999992)
type is <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
shape is ()
ndim is 0
7.749999999999992
```

EDIT: To clarify, I would not expect numpy to even have a dimensionless, shapeless array much less a scipy function return one.

```
print("Numpy version is {}".format(np.__version__))
print("Scipy version is {}".format(scipy.__version__))

Numpy version is 1.10.4
Scipy version is 0.17.0
```

Comment: I can replicate this. Could you specify what your question is? I guess you expect that it should return a `float` and you are asking if this is a bug.

Comment: This related question may help clarify things: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/773030/why-are-0d-arrays-in-numpy-not-considered-scalar

Comment: I don't find it strange that the interpolated value for 2.5 is somewhere in between 7 and 9, given that f(2) = 7 and f(3) = 9.

Comment: @Forzaa- the problem is not the interpolated value, it's the dimensionless, shapeless array returned. I agree the value itself is correct.

Comment: @RyanJ.Smith That perfectly clears it up. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `interp1d` returns a value that matches the input in shape - after wrapping in `np.array()` if needed:

```
In [324]: f([1,2,3])
Out[324]: array([ 5.,  7.,  9.])

In [325]: f([2.5])
Out[325]: array([ 7.75])

In [326]: f(2.5)
Out[326]: array(7.75)

In [327]: f(np.array(2.5))
Out[327]: array(7.75)
```

Many `numpy` operations do return scalars instead of 0d arrays.

```
In [330]: np.arange(3).sum()
Out[330]: 3
```

though actually it returns a numpy object

```
In [341]: type(np.arange(3).sum())
Out[341]: numpy.int32
```

which does have a shape `()` and ndim `0`.

Whereas `interp1d` returns an array.

```
In [344]: type(f(2.5))
Out[344]: numpy.ndarray
```

You can extract the value with `[()]` indexing

```
In [345]: f(2.5)[()]
Out[345]: 7.75

In [346]: type(f(2.5)[()])
Out[346]: numpy.float64
```

This may just be an oversight in the `scipy` code.  How often do people want to interpolate at just one point?  Isn't interpolating over a regular grid of points more common?

==================

The documentation for `f.__call__` is quite explicit about returning an array.

```
Evaluate the interpolant

Parameters
----------
x : array_like
    Points to evaluate the interpolant at.

Returns
-------
y : array_like
    Interpolated values. Shape is determined by replacing
    the interpolation axis in the original array with the shape of x.
```

===============

The other side to the question is why does `numpy` even have a 0d array.  The linked answer probably is sufficient.  But often the question is asked by people who are used to MATLAB.  In MATLAB nearly everything is 2d.  There aren't any (true) scalars.  Now MATLAB has structures and cells, and matrices with more than 2 dimensions.  But I recall a time (in the 1990s) when it didn't have those.  Everything, literal, was a 2d matrix.

The `np.matrix` approximates that MATLAB case, fixing its arrays at 2d. But it does have a `_collapse` method that can return a 'scalar'.