# NumPy, RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power

Tags: python, numpy

I am working with Python 3.6.
I am really confused, why this happened ?

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: a = np.array(-1)

In [3]: a
Out[3]: array(-1)

In [4]: a ** (1/3)
/Users/wonderful/anaconda/bin/ipython:1: RuntimeWarning: invalid        value encountered in power
  #!/Users/wonderful/anaconda/bin/python
Out[4]: nan
```

Comment: For one numpy does not consider 0d arrays as scalars. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773030/why-are-0d-arrays-in-numpy-not-considered-scalar

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Numpy does not seem to allow fractional powers of negative numbers, even if the power would not result in a complex number. (I actually had this same problem earlier today, unrelatedly). One workaround is to use

```
np.sign(a) * (np.abs(a)) ** (1 / 3)
```

Comment: Yeah I like the answer this code generates better.  So much simpler than having to deal with floating point error.

Answer (score 12):

change the dtype to complex numbers

```
a = np.array(-1, dtype=np.complex128)
```

The problem arises when you are working with roots of negative numbers.

Comment: In [5]: a = np.array(-1, dtype=np.complex)

    In [6]: a ** (1/3)
    Out[6]: (0.50000000000000011+0.8660254037844386j)