# In Python 3.6, why does a negative number to the power of a fraction return nan when in a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I have started learning Python recently and I've been going through the [NumPy official quickstart guide](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-dev/user/quickstart.html#indexing-slicing-and-iterating) which includes this example for iterating.

```
>>> a
array([-1000,     1, -1000,    27, -1000,   125,   216,   343,   512,   
729])
>>> for i in a:
...     print(i**(1/3.))
...
nan
1.0
nan
3.0
nan
5.0
6.0
7.0
8.0
9.0
```

However, if I just try to raise -1000 to the power of (1/3.) outside of the loop it returns a value.

```
>>> -1000**(1/3.)
-9.999999999999998
```

With parentheses around -1000 it also returns a value.

```
>>> (-1000)**(1/3.)
(5+8.660254037844384j)
```

Why is it that the same action returns `nan` in the for loop? I'm using Python 3.6.3 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit). I also tried with different fractions that do not round up and it's the same. With a fraction that rounds up to .0 it works though.

I couldn't find a similar question. Excuse me if I'm missing something very obvious.

**Edit:**
A few comments mentioned that the question duplicates [NumPy, RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45384602/numpy-runtimewarning-invalid-value-encountered-in-power)
 and it's true, the problem was I didn't see such an error. The discussion there, however, seems to include a few possible workarounds.

Comment: You have a point, I'll edit it.

Comment: @DeepSpace I get the same as OP does with vanilla Python 3.6. Same [here](https://repl.it/repls/BonyWhimsicalKilobyte) too

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Yeah, managed to reproduce this. This only seems to happen with specific numbers

Comment: `np.power(-1000, 1/3.)` to reproduce.

Comment: Here's a possible  duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45384602/numpy-runtimewarning-invalid-value-encountered-in-power

Comment: @Ev.Kounis I tried with various negative numbers and fractions, the result was always `nan` if the fraction doesn't round.

Comment: @ayhan thank you, as there was no RuntimeWarning I couldn't look it up like that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NumPy, RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45384602/numpy-runtimewarning-invalid-value-encountered-in-power)

Comment: numpy.int32 type behaves differently than python int type

Comment: @NikolayD Probably your environment is silencing those warnings. I think Canopy was doing something like that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Exponentiation in python has higher precedence than the negative operator. Thus `-1000**(1/3)` is equivalent to `-(1000**(1/3))`.

When you doing this operation **inside** the loop you get `(-1000)**(1/3)`. This equal to `10 * (-1**(1/3))` which a **complex** number. Now the array you have, uses a default data type since you did not define any that is determined according to the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.array.html) as follows:

> **dtype :** *data-type, optional*
>
> The desired data-type for the array. If not given, then the type will be determined as the minimum type required to hold the objects in the sequence. This argument can only be used to ‘upcast’ the array. For downcasting, use the .astype(t) method.

So it is probably `np.int16`.

Putting all the information together, we can conclude that your array *is not equipped* with the appropriate `dtype` attribute to be able to *hold* the result of `(-1000)**(1/3)` even though the result **exists**.

This does not happen **outside** arrays since there, no `dtype` is assumed.

---

Fix \ Workaround:

```
>>> a = np.array([-1000, 1], dtype=np.complex)
>>> for i in a:
...     print(i**(1/3.))
...
(5+8.66025403784j)
(1+0j)
```

Comment: @Ev. Kounis, thanks for promoting this answer to the upper level.

Comment: If you want to work with complex numbers, there are of course numpy datatypes you can use for that as well, for example `complex128`, which uses a 64 bit float each for the real and imaginary parts.

Comment: @HåkenLid We are doing that in the **Fix** section of the answer.

Comment: should take | | of the  complex number, not many people would know that is 10.

Comment: It's not that the array is not 'able to hold' the result since the result will be in a distinct array, in fact `np.arange(-10, 10, dtype=np.int8)**(1j/3j)` works fine. It is more likely to be something related to [type  promotion rules](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.result_type.html) (Sorry, couldn't find a good reference)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!

Comment: How do you get Python to use the "basic" power ** instead of np.power when inside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

This is just a short cut to fix it for your question.

```
 def ownpow(a, b):
        if a > 0:
            return a**b
        if a < 0:
            temp = abs(a)**b
            return -1*temp

    a= np.array([-1000,     1, -1000,    27, -1000,   125,   216,   343,   512,  729]) 

    for i in a:
        print(ownpow(i,(1/3.)))
```

apparent numpy array values cannot be raised to negative number, as this could result in complex numbers.

Comment: Thank you for the idea, Gijs.