# Python Code return blank graph. How can I correct this error?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graphing

## Figure

```
x  =  np.linspace(2010,2210,20)


Tline, =  plt.plot(x,T, label="No Taxation",  linewidth=2)
TtaxLine, =  plt.plot(x,T_tax, label= "Ad Valorem", linestyle='--',  linewidth=2)
TunitLine,=  plt.plot(x,T_unit, label="Per  Unit Tax", linewidth=2)
legend= plt.legend(handles=[Tline,  TtaxLine, TunitLine], loc="upper left")
plt.title ('Effect of Taxation on   Mean  Temperature', fontsize=16)
plt.xlabel('Year')
plt.ylabel('Degrees Celsius')
plt.show ()
```

the graph is produced but no lines in the graph

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the following variables:

```
T
T_tax
T_unit
```

(And do imports at the top):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
```

Comment: I have the variables specify however, I am still getting an empty graph.

Comment: What environment are you running this from? Are you running it as a script or line-by-line? Are you getting any error messages? 
Have a look this:
https://repl.it/@NikolajKiel/matplotlib-graph#main.py

Comment: I am running it in script. there was one error concerning scalars.

Comment: https://repl.it/@AustinBraynen/matplotlib-graph#main.py this is my code one line is coming u now. I need the others to come up. i would be grateful for the help.

Comment: This is due to a fractional exponent and numpy's handling of unspecified dtypes, please refer to this explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/49029425/6947748. As stated, the quick fix would be to modify the dtype, after you've created the np.array of np.float64's, see https://repl.it/@NikolajKiel/matplotlib-graph-1#main.py (E.dtype = np.complex).

Comment: There is an error I don't see the graphs coming up in the output screen.

Comment: Sorry, should have been: E = np.array(E, dtype=np.complex), or simpler, added at array definition in the beginning of the script (E = np.arange(20, dtype=np.complex))

Comment: thank you so much. Still having problems with the curve. Cant get the third line to appear. thank you.

Comment: still unavailable to generate a proper graph from the code above.