# NumPy, RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power. How can I get see the value of my variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, error-handling

`NumPy, RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power`

Sometimes I get this in a long and confusing algorithms. How can I get more information out if it. For instance the exact line where it goes wrong and what the values are at that time.
for instance if I have a function like this:

```
def func(x):
    for i in range(100):
        " do something with  x , y
```

And I use the function

```
test = func(x)
>  NumPy, RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power
```

How can see the the values of `x,y,i` at the time of failure?

I have looked at this [NumPy, RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45384602/numpy-runtimewarning-invalid-value-encountered-in-power) which does not answer my question because it explains how to avoid it but how get the specific information I want to.

**EDIT**
I have tried:

```
x = np.random.randint(100)
try:
    test = func( x )
except:
    pass
```

But I don't how to use the pass function to get the desired information?
[Why is "except: pass" a bad programming practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553327/why-is-except-pass-a-bad-programming-practice)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NumPy, RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45384602/numpy-runtimewarning-invalid-value-encountered-in-power)

Answer (score 0):

Use try and except and debug:

```
try:
    test = def(x)
except:
    pass(debug here)
```

Comment: you mean `test = func(x)`?. How should I call the `pass` function?

Comment: `pass` is no a function.
You should to add debug point on this line

Comment: I have not much experience in debugging Python. Is it possible if you can add a few words on how to do it? I am using Spyder