# Plot 3D graph using Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I trying to plot a graph of a function `f(x, y) = x**x*y`, but I'm getting an error:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def f(x,y):
    return x**x*y

x = np.arange(-4.0, 4.0, 0.1)
y = np.arange(-4.0, 4.0, 0.1)
z = f(x, y)
X, Y, Z = np.meshgrid(x, y, z)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.show()
```

First error is:

> /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:2: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power

And the second is:

> ValueError: Argument Z must be 2-dimensional.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```py
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = f(X, Y)
```

The [`meshgrid`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) function returns *coordinate matrices from coordinate vectors.*. Then, you can apply the function and plot it.

For the *"RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power"* warning, that is related to the decimal power on `numpy` objects. Please have a look at this topic *[NumPy, RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45384602/10041823)* for more details.

---

**Full code:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def f(x,y):
    return x**x*y

x = np.arange(-4.0, 4.0, 0.1)
y = np.arange(-4.0, 4.0, 0.1)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = f(X, Y)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = Axes3D(fig)
ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.show()
```

**Output:**

[image]