# Define a function with a fractional power in python

Tags: python, numpy, symbolic-math

I want to defining the following function:

```
def f(x,y):
    return  pow(x, 1/3) + y

x = np.linspace(-1, 1, 10)
y = np.linspace(-1, 1, 10)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = f(X, Y)
```

where clearly x is raised to a fractional power. I want to keep x and y symbolic since I want to plot the corresponding surface later.

However, numpy seems to be unable to handle fractional powers:

```
<ipython-input-96-bb0ed6d3607a>:2: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in float_power
  return  np.float_power(x, 1/2, dtype=float)
```

**Is there a quick shortaround this problem?** I have searched for similar questions on SO but they all involve np.arrays or such with prescribed types of variables.

Comment: The error you show isn't from the code you've posted. Please provide a [mcve] that will produce the error you are getting.

Comment: Is it any better if you use the `**` exponentiation operator?

Comment: see [documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.power.html), *Negative values raised to a non-integral value will result in nan (and a warning will be generated)*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NumPy, RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in power](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45384602/numpy-runtimewarning-invalid-value-encountered-in-power)