# scipy.optimize.minimize returning zero-dimensional array?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, numpy-ndarray

Calling the Powell minimizer for a single-dimensional problem is creating an `OptimizeResult` with an inaccessible value.  For example:

```
from scipy.optimize import minimize
test = minimize(lambda x: 1.0, np.array([1.0]), method="Powell")
```

If I then ask for `test.x` I get:

```
array(3.58792896)
```

Something is wrong with that "array": I can't get the value out of it. For example, `test.x[0]` returns `IndexError: too many indices for array`.  It's like it's a zero-dimensional array, or there's some other reference problem.

(A well-formed `ndarray` would display like `array([3.58792896])`.)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Numpy has zero dimensional arrays: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773030/why-are-0d-arrays-in-numpy-not-considered-scalar

Comment: Get the value with `test.x[()]`.

Comment: That is indeed a zero-dimensional array, but while zero-dimensional arrays are entirely supported in NumPy, that `minimize` call still shouldn't be making one.

Comment: This could be a bug. As the documentation says, the result should have same length as input. All other methods except `Powell` have this behaviour. Maybe report this on the github issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a 0-dimensional array, but it shouldn't be. While 0-dimensional arrays are a supported concept in NumPy, that `minimize` call shouldn't be creating one. [It looks like the devs are worried about breaking backward compatibility if they fix this](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/6673), so a fix is unlikely for now.

I would recommend using [`numpy.atleast_1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.atleast_1d.html) to handle this case consistently with the cases that return a 1D array, and be forward compatible if they do eventually change the return value:

```
test = minimize(...)
if not test.success:
    handle_that()
result = np.atleast_1d(test.x)
```

For cases where you expect a 0D array and want to retrieve the stored value, index it with a tuple of 0 indices:

```
value = zero_d_array[()]
```