# numpy: how to check if two 0D arrays are same class?

Tags: python, numpy

I have two 0D numpy arrays and want to check if they are same class. The first one `y1` is obtained by matmul two 1D arrays; and the second `y2` is obtained by squeezing a 1D array.

```py
import numpy as np

y1 = np.array([1]) @ np.array([5])
y2 = np.array([3]).squeeze()

y1.ndim == y2.ndim == 0  # -> True
y1.__class__ is np.ndarray  # -> False
y2.__class__ is np.ndarray  # -> True
```

as shown above, `y1` and `y2` are both 0D.
If `y1` is not a ndarray, what is it?

In my actual case, `y1` is just matmul of two numpy arrays, whose output can be a numpy array, or not, as show above; `y2` come from some other operations, whose output should be same class as `y1`, so I have an assertion: `assert y1.__class__ is y2.__class__`. and this fails when y1 is matmul of two 1D arrays. What should I do then? Thanks!

Comment: "what is it?" did you try checking `type(y1)`?

Comment: it's ```numpy.int64```

Comment: Yes I checked. Just confused why the output from matmul is not a numpy array, but a datatype like np.int64?

Comment: Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773030/why-are-0d-arrays-in-numpy-not-considered-scalar

Comment: A `numpy.int64` is an `array scalar`, https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html.  It has a lot of the same attributes and methods as a 0d `ndarray`.  Check the type of the element of `y2`, `type(y2[()])`.

Comment: Why are you using this class assertion?  What different classes are you watching for?  Here you've uncovered the distinction between a `ndarray` and an `array scalar`.  Anything else you are worried about?

Comment: I'm also watching for `cupy` arrays. I need to assert that `y1` and `y2` are either both numpy arrays, or both cupy arrays