# Why does operating on a 0d Numpy array give a Numpy float?

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point, numpy-ndarray

Let's say I have a 0d Numpy array:

```
x = numpy.asarray(1.)
```

This has type `numpy.ndarray`. But now operate on `x`:

```
y = 1.*x
```

This now has type `numpy.float64`. The same thing is true when using all Numpy functions. For example, `numpy.sin(x)` has type `numpy.float64`.

Why?!

Now let's say I have a function and in the course of operation that function has to promote the dimension of the array (to perform some check or other):

```py
def fun(x):
    x = np.asarray(x)
    if x.ndim == 0:
        x = x[None]
    # Perform some checks and operate on x
    return x.squeeze()
```

To be consistent with Numpy I would like this function to return a `numpy.float64` when a float is passed to it. But as it stands it returns a 0d array. I could instead return `1.*x.squeeze()` but that seems very ugly. Is there a canonical solution to this problem?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/773030/843953

Comment: When writing your own functions is there a way of emulating this behaviour, so as to be consistent with Numpy functions?

Comment: I think it should take care of itself unless you specifically construct an array to return. Can you [edit] your question to include an example of a function you're writing where this is a problem?

Comment: Yes, you're right. I think I'm conflating two issues. But let's say that once in a function you have to promote the dimension of `x` (to perform some check): `x = x[None]`. You can squeeze back down to get a 0d array: `x.squeeze()`. But I would like to return a `numpy.float64` if a float is passed to the function. I can use a flag and then do `1.*x.squeeze()` but it seems ugly. Happy to update the question if you don't think I'm muddying the waters.

Comment: Feel free to update the question, that seems to be the actual question anyway.

Comment: There's a lot of overlap between `numpy scalars` and 0d arrays..https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.scalars.html

Comment: Yes indeed. But I can't see an appropriate casting method when using Numpy to operate on floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A python scalar, a 0d array, and a numpy scalar:

```
In [134]: x=1.23; y = np.array(x); z = 1.*y    
In [135]: x,y,z
Out[135]: (1.23, array(1.23), 1.23)    
In [136]: type(x),type(y),type(z)
Out[136]: (float, numpy.ndarray, numpy.float64)
```

As the `numpy scalars` page notes, there's a lot of overlap between such a scalar and a 0d array.

They can both be indexed

```
In [137]: y[()], z[()]
Out[137]: (1.23, 1.23)
    
In [139]: y[()]=2.3;y
Out[139]: array(2.3)
```

The key difference is the scalar cannot be changed:

```
In [140]: z[()]=2.34
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[140], line 1
----> 1 z[()]=2.34

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object does not support item assignment
```

Why do many operations return a scalar instead of a 0d array?  My guess is that there's a 'finalize' method that does this sort of 'clean up'.  Documentation on subclassing arrays talks about this sort of finalization.

There are several ways of making such an array is atleast 1d.

```
In [141]: y[None], np.atleast_1d(x), np.array(x, ndmin=1)
Out[141]: (array([2.3]), array([1.23]), array([1.23]))
```

`np.squeeze` explicitly notes that it will return a 0d array, not a numpy scalar.  I'm not aware of any other operations that make such a distinction.

The doc for `np.inscalar` may instructive in this:

```
In [143]: np.isscalar(y), np.isscalar(z)
Out[143]: (False, True)

In [144]: y.ndim, z.ndim
Out[144]: (0, 0)
```

`isscalar` is python code, with several `isinstance` tests.

Comment: Thank you very much. A finalize method makes perfect sense and would indeed explain why operations on 0d arrays return scalars. It also makes sense that squeezing all axes returns a 0d array (thanks for pointing me to the documentation). When it comes to function construction I think the correct procedure is to check floats and arrays separately. Any subsequent operations then return the expected type (as [@pho](https://stackoverflow.com/users/843953/pho) points out).

Comment: FWIW I wrote a short [blog post](https://amerygration.com/Blog/python_functions_taking_float_and_array-like_arguments.html) summarizing all this.